# How to see the table list in android

Tags: android, sqlite

[Here I have attached an image of an SQLite database structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXrKx.png)
When I open the list of the tables from ADB shell it shows only 2 table but there are 59 tables.

```
sqlite> .tables
.tables
android_metadata
```

How can I see the table list in Android SQLite from ADB shell?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite

Comment: http://vinnysoft.blogspot.in/2009/09/creating-databases-from-sqlite-shell.html

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite i visit this link and when i type .tables command it adb shell it doesn't show any table list but my db is contain 59 tables u can see in my attachment image.

Comment: try it with any GUI tool once like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: Actually i have attach the span shoot that is taken from mozilla add on i want to implement the ORMLITE and when create a DAO it will create a extra tables.that's why i am tring it from adb shell command?can you please help me...?

Answer (score 0):

I have used 2 stand alone programs on my Windows 7 platform; SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1 and sqlitestudio.  If you are using eclipse you and add the plugin SQLLIteManager, com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0.jar.

Hope this helps.